# Making sure traffic does not bypass shuttle when ssh connection breaks

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunneling

I would like to use `sshuttle` on machine *A* to vpn all my traffic from behind a firewall. My remote, machine *B* is a raspberry pi at my house connected to a ddns service (I am too cheap to get a static ip). The goal is to make machine *A* access the internet only and only through machine *B*.

I have been successfully tunneling some ports from A to B and sometimes ssh connection hangs.

How do I make sure that the machine *A* behind the firewall can only access the internet though `sshuttle` via machine *B*? In other words, when ssh connection breaks machine *A* should not go online.

Comment: The question is confusing. I see that there are several machines involved, and that there is some software involved. Only I don't know how many, and I don't know what software is running on what, or what OS is running on what.

Comment: There seems to be two questions: "How do I **stop** circumvention?", "How do i re**start** a connection?". Both will have very different answers.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor is the question clear now?